# Copy pasting tables from Excel to word including a line break, but use only Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am working on a file where i have populated a lot of tables in excel using VBA. Following this i want to paste the tables one by one into word. Once i paste a table for some reason, the cursor is stuck at Cell 1 of the first table and when i paste the second table it gets paste into the first cell.

I want to know if there is way to introduce line break or page break following pasting the first table or if i can even move the active cursor to outside of the table.

All the options ive found so far are on word but i dont want to use word. I want to introduce a line break in word after the table using excel VBA.

Can someone help me with this? Is there a way to move the cursor or introduce line break after pasting the table?

The code is as follows:

```
WSout.Cells(2, 5).Copy
With myDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection
 .EndOf Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
 .TypeParagraph
 '.TypeText (str)
 .TypeParagraph
End With
myDoc.Paragraphs(ba).Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'For Table 1
ba = 1 + ba

WSout.Range("N1:O22").Copy
myDoc.Paragraphs(ba).Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting

myDoc.Application.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=23

'WordApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=23

'For Table 2

ba = 1 + ba

lastrow = "0"
lastcol = "22"

For bb = 2 To WSout.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

lastrow = 1 + lastrow

Next bb

WSout.Range("Q1", WSout.Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Copy
myDoc.Paragraphs(ba).Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that 'ba = 1 + ba' with 'myDoc.Paragraphs(ba).Range' only points to the second logical paragraph in your original selection - you haven't updated 'ba' to match the 'Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=23'. In any event, working with Selection objects is inefficient; you should use Range objects instead. Try something along the lines of:

```
With myDoc.Range
  .InsertAfter vbCr & WSout.Cells(2, 5).Text & vbCr
  WSout.Range("N1:O22").Copy
  .Characters.Last.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
  .InsertAfter vbCr
  With WSout
    .Range("Q1:V" & .Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
  End With
  .Characters.Last.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the pitfall of selection now! Your solution seems help me get the work done. But i have one follow-up question if you dont mind. As i have mentioned above, i have multiple tables in different styles of matrix. I cannot have a fixed range as you have mentioned above. Can you help with a suggestion to modify the code according let us say variables of "First row", "First column", "lastrow" and "lastcolumn" of each table?

Comment: «I cannot have a fixed range as you have mentioned above» If you study the code, you'll see that it does not use a fixed range - it keeps moving to whatever is the new end of the document. You should start a new thread for your final question.

Answer (score 0):

You move your selection, but then your second paste repeats the first - so it pastes into exactly the same location. These lines-

```
  WSout.Range("Q1", WSout.Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Copy
  myDoc.Paragraphs(ba).Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
```

Should be something like

```
    WSout.Range("Q1", WSout.Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Copy
    myDoc.selection.Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
```

I say something like because I'm on my phone and can't test this